# Method investigation in Eclipse - How to find out which classes call this particular method?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

say I have **Class1** that implements interface named **Class1interface**.

This interface is autowired via dependency injection and IoC into another class - name it **Class2**. **Class2** uses **SOME** of the methods provided by **Class1interface**.

Say we use Spring notation:

```
class Class2 {
   @Autowired 
   Class1interface;
   // methods calls of Class1interface and application logic
}
```

How can I find out which methods of Class1interface/Class1 are used in Class2 without scrolling through the screen? Or how can I check whether this particular Class1interface method is used in Class2?

I know dodgy explanation, but I tried my best.

Thank You,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> while the cursor is on a method will show references to that method.  This won't get you a pretty report of class relationships, but you could look through the results of Class1.blah to see which methods in Class2 reference it.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean at runtime, you'd have to use reflection to pull the list of methods.

```
Method[] list1 = Class1.class.getMethods();
Method[] list2 = Class2.class.getMethods();
//Your code to compare the lists here
```

If you mean dev environment, go with the answer by @digitaljoel

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use "Ctrl + shift + U" while you place the cursor on the field reference , you should able to see the usage of the field reference in that class.

Answer (score 0):

- If you click on the field, all references to it are highlighted automatically. You see them as small rectangles at the right side of the code; you can click them to get to the position where the field is used.
- `Search > Occurences in File > Identifier` gives you a list of all access to the field.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact solution, but might be of help:

Place the cursor over any field or method and press `<Ctrl>`+`<Alt>`+`<H>`, which will give you the call hierarchy. 
This still means that you have to check for each method in `Class1`/`Interface1`